# Is it possible to configure Docker to pull from my GitHub repo?

Tags: git, docker

I want to create an image and put it on my GitHub account repository, to work on it and then to use a Docker instance.

Is it possible to make this repo pullable by a Docker instance, like this?

```
docker pull https://github.com/basharov/my-docker-image.git
```

I see it's possible to use remote urls for `pull` command but not exactly for git repos.

Comment: no, you have to use https://docs.docker.com/registry/

Comment: While I am in the begining of the path, should I look at https://coreos.com/blog/rocket/ instead of Docker?

Comment: the closest thing to your request, I can think of, is gitlab, http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/container_registry/README.html
you can have docker registry in a project. 

it's kind of neat to have all your project files and related images in one place

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noticed you can pull from a different url, which is described here [**Pulling from a different registry**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#/pulling-from-a-different-registry)

> By default, docker pull pulls images from Docker Hub. It is also
>   possible to manually specify the path of a registry to pull from. For
>   example, if you have set up a local registry, you can specify its path
>   to pull from it. A registry path is similar to a URL, but does not
>   contain a protocol specifier (https://).

`docker pull` expects a **registry** behind the url and not just a file storage. The registry has to comply with the docker api. There is a doc on how to start a private registry: [**Deploying a registry server**](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). What you can do is replace the storage driver with one listed here Docker [Registry Storage Driver](https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/) however github is not seen as a storage driver.

Answer (score 0):

When you run 'docker pull', you are pulling a packaged docker image, containing os libs, JDK, jars, your application binaries, etc. Everything needed to run your application, not just source code stored on Github. The docker build command allows you to build the image.

Usually, you need to setup a build server such as Jenkins which will at a min 1. clone your github repo, 2. build it, and 3. publish to Docker Hub or some other Docker registry.

I believe Docker Hub now has a paid hosted solution so you don't need to set up a build server and all yourself but I haven't used it before so can't comment.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/github/#/creating-an-automated-build